# deleting columns from influx DN using flux command line

Tags: influxdb, flux, influxdb-2, flux-influxdb

Is there any way to delete columns of an influx timeseries as we have accidentally injected data using the wrong data type (int instead of float).
Or to change the type of data instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to delete a "column" (i.e. a tag or a field) from an Influx measurement so far. Here's the [feature request](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/6150) for that but there is no ETA yet.

Three workarounds:

1. use **SELECT INTO** to copy the desirable data into a different measurement, excluding the undesirable "columns". e.g.:

   ```
   SELECT desirableTag1, desirableTag2, desirableField1, desirableField2 INTO new_measurement FROM measurement
   ```
2. use **[CAST operations](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/query_language/explore-data/#cast-operations)** to "change the data type" from float to int. e.g.:

   ```
   SELECT desirableTag1, desirableTag2, desirableField1, desirableField2, undesiredableTag3::integer, undesiredableField3::integer INTO new_measurement FROM measurement
   ```
3. "Update" the data with **insert statement**, which will overwrite the data with the same timestamp, same tags, same field keys. Keep all other things equal, except that the "columns" that you would like to update. To make the data in integer data type, remember to put a trailing i on the number. Example: 42i. e.g.:

   ```
   insert measurement,desirableTag1=v1 desirableField1=fv1,desirableField2=fv2,undesirableField1=someValueA-i 1505799797664800000
   insert measurement,desirableTag1=v21 desirableField1=fv21,desirableField2=fv22,undesirableField1=someValueB-i 1505799797664800000
   ```